# Query String Array JSON

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table in Athena, where the data ingestion was done through a MongoDB, where a column of the table is an array of JSON.

Only the table column is as a string, and I don't know how to run a query.

```
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| client | information                                                                                                                           |
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | [ { "ProductId" : { "$binary" : "7KgRQKabqkuxE+1pSw9b7Q==", "$type" : "03" }, "Risk" : "0", "Due_data" : { "$date" : 1634860800000 } ]|
+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to know if I can run a query to leave the table like this

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| client | ProductId                            | Risk | Due_data            |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | 4011A8EC-9BA6-4BAA-B113-ED694B0F5BED | 0    | 2021-12-08 00:00:00 |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the techniques shown on [Extracting Data from JSON - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with arrays is not as easy because Presto does not fully support jsonpath. If you are guaranteed to have only one element in array you can do just something like `json_extract_scalar(json, '$[0].ProductId["$binary"]')` to extract fields, otherwise you can cast json to array of json and work with that:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (client, information) AS (
    VALUES (1, '[ { "ProductId" : { "$binary" : "7KgRQKabqkuxE+1pSw9b7Q==", "$type" : "03" }, "Risk" : "0", "Due_data" : { "$date" : 1634860800000 }} ]')
) 

--query
SELECT client,
    r.product_id,
    r.risk,
    r.ts
FROM dataset
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        transform(
            cast(json_parse(information) as array(json)), -- parse json and treat as array of json
            json->cast( -- transform concrete json to row
                ROW(
                    json_extract_scalar(json, '$.ProductId["$binary"]'),
                    json_extract_scalar(json, '$.Risk'),
                    from_unixtime(
                        cast(
                            json_extract_scalar(json, '$.Due_data["$date"]') AS BIGINT
                        ) / 1000 -- transform timestamp to date
                    )
                ) as ROW(product_id VARCHAR, risk INT, ts TIMESTAMP)
            )
        )
    ) as t(r)
```

Output:

| client | product_id | risk | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7KgRQKabqkuxE+1pSw9b7Q== | 0 | 2021-10-22 00:00:00.000 |

Note that this does not handle `product_id` transformation - here you need to provide your logic.

Comment: I can't say there are more elements in the array.
If have more elements how should I do?

Comment: @Bruno everything after _"otherwise you can cast json to array of json and work with that:"_ describes what you can do in case of multiple elements =)

Comment: Column information is like this `[ { "ProductId" : { "$binary" : "7KgRQKabqkuxE+1pSw9b7Q==", "$type" : "03" }, "Risk" : "0", "Due_data" : { "$date" : 1634860800000 }, { "ProductId" : { "$binary" : "HtIO6Q/GLEGDBdtWddp6Xg==", "$type" : "03" }, "Risk" : "0", "Due_data" : { "$date" : 1637452800000 }, { "ProductId" : { "$binary" : "vpUTeuveD0GLmlrzjbhiBg==", "$type" : "03" }, "Risk" : "0", "Due_data" : { "$date" : 1637452800000 } ]` and each json need to be a new row.

Comment: @Bruno code in my answer should do exactly that. have you tried it?

Comment: @Bruno also i tried to use `to_hex(from_base64(...))`  to parse id but it seems the result is incorrect...

Comment: It worked

i figured out how to convert base64 but i don't know how to include this in the query

message_bytes = b64.b64decode(ProductId)
res_uuid = uuid.UUID(bytes_le=message_bytes)

i made this code in pycharm

Comment: @Bruno this is python code, you can't use python code in presto query directly. you need either translate it to sql or in case of Athena you can use it via used defined function ([UDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-udf.html))